# How to use Webpack 4 to compile Sass files properly?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

My code is working but it ends up with unnecessary .js files in the output directory. I'm trying to find a way to get a clean output. To make it clear what I mean I describe my code below:

You can find my project [here](https://github.com/MEDIADUDES/FoundationPress/tree/3a939113242edce8d1aa108f57b0a55f2e92a975).

The Webpack config is the following ([`tasks/options/webpack.js`](https://github.com/MEDIADUDES/FoundationPress/blob/3a939113242edce8d1aa108f57b0a55f2e92a975/tasks/options/webpack.js), I'm using grunt to run webpack if it matters):

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    build: {
        ...
        entry: {
            app: `${path.resolve()}/src/assets/js/app.js`,
            main: `${path.resolve()}/src/assets/sass/main.scss`,
            editor: `${path.resolve()}/src/assets/sass/editor.scss`,
        },
        output: {
            path: `${path.resolve()}/dist/assets/js`,
            filename: '[name].js',
        },
        ...
        devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
        plugins: [
            ...
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                options: {
                    postcss: [autoprefixer()],
                },
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
                // both options are optional
                filename: '../css/[name].css',
            }),
            ...
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|vendor)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                            plugins: [
                                'transform-class-properties',
                                '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader?-url&sourceMap',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                parser: 'postcss-scss',
                                sourceMap: true,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            query: {
                                outputStyle: 'extended',
                                sourceMap: true,
                                sourceMapContents: false,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

If I run this I get the following output in `dist/assets/...`:

- js/app.js
- js/app.js.map
- js/editor.js
- js/editor.js.map
- js/main.js
- js/main.js.map
- css/editor.css
- css/editor.css.map
- css/main.css
- css/main.css.map

where the following files are not needed with only some webpack code in it:

- js/editor.js
- js/editor.js.map
- js/main.js
- js/main.js.map

I get that they are generated because of the output I declared and the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` extracts the (S)CSS code from the .js files.

Isn't there a way where I can say: "If the entry is a SCSS file, output the CSS in `dist/css/[name].css`" instead of first output it in `dist/js/[name].js` then extract the CSS inside this JS file to `dist/css/[name].css` and leaving unused .js files in `dist/js/`?

Maybe it's not how Webpack works.

I surely can run another plugin to clean up the dist folder afterwards but I'm curious if there is a way to put all the files in the right place without leaving files I don't need there.

Hope everything is clear enough, if not please ask. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I've found that some workarounds have been created as plugin to avoid such behavior.
[webpack-fix-style-only-entries](https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries)

And if I read correctly, it has been fix for the next version of webpack (^5)
[webpack git issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7300)