# Webpack compile sass into css file problem

Tags: sass, config, webpack-4

Firstly I'd like to say that I've seen same question but I cannot upvote nor comment to say that I'm in the same need. So it's clearly a duplicate of [How to use Webpack 4 to compile Sass files properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223568/how-to-use-webpack-4-to-compile-sass-files-properly)

I'm just trying to compile some sass file into css file using webpack. But webpack creates some useless js files with the same name as the css files.

The folder Structure:

```
--dist
--src
    |--a
        |--editor.scss
        |--style.scss
    |--b
        |--editor.scss
        |--style.scss
```

and my dependencies (package.json)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "latest",
    "webpack-cli": "latest",
    "css-loader": "latest",
    "sass-loader": "latest",
    "node-sass": "latest",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "latest"
}
```

here the config I've set up already (webpack.config.js):

```js
const path = require("path");
const context = path.resolve(__dirname);
const output = context + "/dist";
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const entries = {
    "/dist/a/editor": "./src/a/editor.scss",
    "/dist/a/style": "./src/a/style.scss",
    "/dist/b/editor": "./src/b/editor.scss",
    "/dist/b/style": "./src/b/style.scss"
};

module.exports = {
    context: context,
    entry: entries,
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "[name].css"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: output
        //     // publicPath: distBlocks,
        //     // filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Actual result**:

```
--dist
    |--a
        |--editor.css
        |--editor.js
        |--style.css
        |--style.js
    |--b
        |--editor.css
        |--editor.js
        |--style.css
        |--style.js
--src
    |--a
        |--editor.scss
        |--style.scss
    |--b
        |--editor.scss
        |--style.scss
```

**Expected result** is the same without those useless js files...

So How webpack is suppose to be configured to get the css file only and no js files from the scss??

**UPDATE**:
Here is a workaround : [webpack-fix-style-only-entries](https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries)

`webpack.config.js`

```j
...
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require("webpack-fix-style-only-entries");
...
Module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "[name].css"
        })
    ],
    ...
```

There is a fix but only for the future version of webpack (^5) if understood correctly [webpack git](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7300)

Comment: Webpack used .js as entry, always. If you don't want any js, then another build tool might be a better fit.

Comment: @anderssonola Ok thanks for pointing this out which is I believe, not entirely true...
[link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/518)
[link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/151)